# Using GL_SHORT instead of GL_FLOAT in an OpenGL ES vertex array

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I have this vertex array of a cube

```
float vertex_coordinates [] = {

-12.43796, -12.43796, 12.43796, -12.43796, 12.43796, 12.43796, 12.43796, 12.43796, 12.43796,
12.43796, 12.43796, 12.43796, 12.43796, -12.43796, 12.43796, -12.43796, -12.43796, 12.43796,
12.43796, -12.43796, -12.43796, 12.43796, 12.43796, -12.43796, -12.43796, 12.43796, -12.43796,
-12.43796, 12.43796, -12.43796, -12.43796, -12.43796, -12.43796, 12.43796, -12.43796, -12.43796,
-12.43796, -12.43796, -12.43796, -12.43796, 12.43796, -12.43796, -12.43796, 12.43796, 12.43796,
-12.43796, 12.43796, 12.43796, -12.43796, -12.43796, 12.43796, -12.43796, -12.43796, -12.43796,
12.43796, -12.43796, 12.43796, 12.43796, 12.43796, 12.43796, 12.43796, 12.43796, -12.43796,
12.43796, 12.43796, -12.43796, 12.43796, -12.43796, -12.43796, 12.43796, -12.43796, 12.43796,
-12.43796, 12.43796, 12.43796, -12.43796, 12.43796, -12.43796, 12.43796, 12.43796, -12.43796,
12.43796, 12.43796, -12.43796, 12.43796, 12.43796, 12.43796, -12.43796, 12.43796, 12.43796,
-12.43796, -12.43796, -12.43796, -12.43796, -12.43796, 12.43796, 12.43796, -12.43796, 12.43796,
12.43796, -12.43796, 12.43796, 12.43796, -12.43796, -12.43796, -12.43796, -12.43796, -12.43796,

};
```

At the moment I render it using

```
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertex__coordinates);

// texture pointer ...

// colour pointer

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, size);
```

How would I go about converting the vertex array into values that would render precisely the same
cube but instead using `GL_SHORT` as the second parameter to glVertexPointer in order to speed up
my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a preprocessing step we calculate the min and max of the object and use this to maximize the utilization of the precision in a short:

```
float modelMin[3] = {FLT_MAX, FLT_MAX, FLT_MAX}; //or std::numeric_limits<float>
float modelMax[3] = {-FLT_MAX, -FLT_MAX, -FLT_MAX};
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
        const float v = vertex_coordinates[i * 3 + j];
        modelMin[j] = std::min(modelMin[j], v);
        modelMax[j] = std::max(modelMax[j], v);
    }
}

short* short_coordinates = new short[size * 3];
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
        const float src = vertex_coordinates[i * 3 + j];
        short& dst = short_coordinats[i * 3 + j];
        dst = (short)floorf(((src - modelMin[j]) / (modelMax[j] - modelMin[j])) * 65536.0f - 32768.0f + 0.5f);
    }
}
```

And when drawing we do the following:

```
const float scale[3], bias[3];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    scale[i] = (modelMax[j] - modelMin[j]) / 65536.0f;
    bias[i] = (32768.0f / 65536.0f) * (modelMax[j] - modelMin[j]) + modelMin[j];
}

glTranslatef(bias[0], bias[1], bias[2]);
glScalef(scale[0], scale[1], scale[2]);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_SHORT, 0, short_coordinates);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, size);
```

/A.B.

Answer (score 0):

instead of (+-)12.43796 use (+-)1

then apply a glScalef operation on your modelview matrix of 12.43796

I doubt this would speed up your code, however. All it will do is reduce your vertex array to half of its original size.

Comment: thanks! however, how would I apply this logic if I had multiple
cubes of different sizes (+-6 for instance)?

Comment: On the iPhone, reductions in the size of the vertex array lead to significant performance boosts.  Switching to shorts from floats boosted my rendering performance by 30% by itself.  Dimitris, to apply this to various cases, you would just need to normalize your floating point values to +-32767.  Find the largest absolute value of any vertex coordinate, and multiply all of your vertex values by 32767 divided by that value.  You then can adjust your model view or projection matrix to match the new scaled size.

Comment: Brad's suggestion works, but only if your model is centered roughly around (0,0,0).  You'll need a regular scale and bias if it's not.